# OTF + microtype quality + Koma-script

Tags: koma-script, microtype, opentype

I stopped using LaTeX some years ago, and I'm wondering if there's now any functional way to use, at the same time:

- Koma Script for great European layout (“Tschicholdian” one);
- OpenType for various professionnal fonts;
- `microtype` for great typographic quality.

I remember I had to choose between OTF fonts and `microtype` (I chose the latter, with Kepler fonts), but I heard LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX could do the trick.
(I'm not a fetishist: if I can manage to have all these advantages with other packages, that would be OK, of course).

Is that correct?

Comment: LuaLaTeX supports more features of the `microtype` package than XeLaTeX, but not all of them.

Comment: Thanks Juri. I've seen around that some OTF fonts are more likely to work perfectly (ie without kerning problems) with Tex variants and that some kind of kerning file must exist or be created manualy. Is there some kind of list with all the kerning files available? I'm not looking for anything fancy (things like Adobe Garamond Pro, Minion Pro or MS Georgia will do).

Comment: With lualatex or xelatex you can use any otf without any additional files. I use Fonts like Adobe garamond or minion pro without problems.

Comment: Ok. Perhaps I'm missing something, but I read there (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161838/fontspec-microtype-fine-tune-opentype-fonts) some microtype user who's talking about tuning protusion values for A. Garamond Pro. Is that outdated? Unnecessary?

Comment: Protrusion is not the same as kerning... Which features of microtype do you need? Also, did you read the *answer* to that question?

Comment: I did. Someone is working on it, if I get it. But I see Charis-SIL (which looks quite good, btw) seems to be better supported when it comes to profusion. Am I right? I'm looking for things such as protusion, expansion — all kinds of spacing in fact: letter and word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, LuaLaTeX as engine, microtype and KOMA-script packages provide such a lot of features, that you will need some time to study it. Where to start?

Install texlive 2014 or the current MikTeX version. Older versions lack of many features of LuaLaTeX, microtype and KOMA-script.

There is a very useful [»Guide to LuaLaTeX«](http://dante.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/luatex/lualatex-doc/lualatex-doc.pdf) by Manuel Pégourié-Gonnard. Then have a quick look into the manual of microtype (»texdoc microtype« on the command line), Table 1.

As you seem interested in typography, please take the time to read the basic sections in the KOMA-script manual about scrlayer, especially about scrlayer-scrpage and scrlayer-notecolumn. People haven't recognised the power of new package `scrlayer`. You can have a main column for you text and a margin column for annotations, longtables and whatever, *even if a pagebreak occurs*.

Comment: Thanks Keks. I think I start to figure out what is now possible with these packages. I used to use Latex and Xetex with Microtype, Koma-script and Kp fonts (ligatures, old figs, etc.), which was great, but now my typographic taste has evolved a little bit, and I think it worth the price to come back to it with an Adobe font bundle, or some Plantin, Calluna, or Essay text font… So I'm gonna look towards scrlayer and Lualatex, as you say.